# HP logo stays more than 15s in all Linux distributions

Tags: boot, hp

I own a HP ProBook 450 G5 Notebook PC, with **Windows 10 the startup HP logo stays less than 5s whereas with linux distributions it stays more than 15s,** I've tried Ubuntu, Linux mint,  Linux lite, but the results were unchanged.

Comment: During start-up?  While the logo is up, is there hard disk activity or does the computer appear frozen?  If there is hard disk activity, it means it's going through the start-up process.  How long Linux is vs Windows is a bit meaningless since they each have a different start-up time...  Perhaps, Windows starts up quicker but programs later take longer to start, etc.  I wouldn't worry about it...if the system is loading up.

Comment: its not about startup time, its about the hp logo which appears exactly after the start button is pressed seems like hp is searching for the start point

Comment: Is this HP logo appearing between the moment the computer turns on until when the login prompt appears?  If so, then the system is just starting up.  Or is it after the login prompt because Linux doesn't have a "Start button" (as far as I know).

Comment: sorry, "start button" means the laptop's on button, the logo appears exactly after I switch on the laptop and stays more than 15s then the ubuntu or other distros logo appears

Comment: Yes...  That is what I meant in my original comment.  Between when you hit the "on" button and the login prompt appears, the system is starting up.  *If* the hard disk is still being read during this 5 s / 15 s, then that means the computer is doing "work"...  So, Linux is just taking longer to start than Windows.  The "HP logo" that you see is just something shown to you during this start-up process...

Comment: For sure something to do with secure boot / UEFI or something like that.

Comment: If your UEFI boot settings are looking for an invalid startup device, this can happen. Check your BIOS settings.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Your question though makes little sense; you mention *all linux* but have only tested & mention distros that use Ubuntu kernels? though without specifics too like product/release or kernel stack choice (*so may actually have tested only a single kernel*!)   Please stay on topic & provide (specific) information that is useful, not vague.

Comment: Unless you disable **Fast Startup** in Windows, an hibernation feature, you shouldn't be comparing. Disabling this i¡when dual-booting is a must and generally recommended even with only Windows. That should be all.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP Probook 440 G7 running Ubuntu 20.04.4 and takes 29 secs from switching on to reaching the password prompt. I've been unable to shorten this despite extensive research, changing settings in BIOS and disabling the top line using systemd-analyze. I'll live with it!

Since Windows cheat with their start up, if you want to see a comparison with another OS, just turn off fast boot in BIOS and you'll find Windows much slower to get to the login screen.
Fast boot just puts Windows into a "hibernation" state ensuring a quick start up.

More research and using `dmesg -T > /tmp/myBoot.txt; gedit /tmp/myBoot.txt`    I find that waiting for the ipv6 connection is taking 9-11 seconds.
I'll do more checking to see if it is wise to disable ipv6.

Unfortunately I am unable to reach a decision as there appears to be no definitive answer.